# How to handle division by zero in mongodb with morphia?

Tags: mongodb, morphia, mongodb-aggregation

I found this: [Handle division by zero in mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841266/how-to-handle-division-by-zero-in-mongodb-aggregation-framework) useful if I were using mongoDB directly, to resolve division by zero issue, but I couldn't found a way of doing this with ***Morphia***.

What I need to accomplish is exactly what the refered question says, but using Morphia, that's why I don't show further code examples.
Anyone could give me a tip of how can I do a division with morphia aggregation projection and returns 0 result in cases where divisor is zero?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [Projection](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.2/javadoc/org/mongodb/morphia/aggregation/Projection.html) class for that purpose.

```
import static org.mongodb.morphia.aggregation.Projection.divide;
import static org.mongodb.morphia.aggregation.Projection.expression;
import static org.mongodb.morphia.aggregation.Projection.projection;    
...
final AggregationPipeline pipeline = datastore.createAggregation(ItemEntity.class)
                .project(projection("_id").suppress(),
                        projection("name", "name"),
                        projection("upvotes", "upvotes"),
                        projection("downvotes", "downvotes"), 
                        projection("quality", expression("$cond", expression(FilterOperator.EQUAL.val(), projection("downvotes"), 0), projection("upvotes"), divide(projection("upvotes"), projection("downvotes"))))
                )
                .sort(Sort.descending("quality"));
```